# Convert values from a Dictionary<string, object> with T

Tags: c#, casting

I have a class that inherits from Dictionary like this

```
public class ManagedSettings : Dictionary<string, object>
```

Because I want to be able to do this

```
public object this[string key, bool myVar = true]
{
    get{...}
    set{...}
}
```

So the user can do

```
managerSettingVar["hisKey"] = hisValue;
```

But now I want to allow the user to do something like this

```
managerSettingVar<bool>["hisKey"]
```

So the value from the key "hisKey" comes casted as a bool already.
Is that even possible as I'm suggesting? I tried using the T but haven't been lucky yet.
Something like

```
public T this<T>[string key, bool myVar = true]
```

Comment: What do you want to do with 'hisVar'. I see it in your signature, but not coming back in the code.

Comment: What's the purpose of `T` on the last line?

Comment: myVar hisVar whatever.. I need to use it inside the get set methods

Comment: the second T was so the user could do this managerSettingVar<bool>["hisKey"]

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible. Indexers cannot be made generic.

You can create a generic GetValue function:

```
public T GetValue<T>(string key)
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(this[key], typeof(T));
}
```

or, of the values only need to be casted:

```
public T GetValue<T>(string key)
{
    return (T)this[key];
}
```

Comment: Your missing the `<T>` after the method names.

Comment: @juharr: Thank! I was to hasty. Did not have coffee yet. :)